# Can not connect to database in asp core net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am trying to connect to a mysql database using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql and i know other people have asked similar question, but i did not find any solution that works for me. Also I should say that i can acess the database through my workbench and it also worked when i installed the database locally and used "localhost" instead of an ip. Here is my code:

appsettings.json(i removed the Credentials but i am sure they are correct since i am using the same in the workbench)

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "WebApiDatabase": "Server=<ipaddress>; port=3306; Database=<dbname>;Uid=<user>;pwd=<pw>;Connection Timeout=10;"
},
```

and the programm.cs

```
string verbindungsString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiDatabase");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(verbindungsString);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<EtikettenContext>(options =>
        options.UseMySql(verbindungsString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(verbindungsString),
                options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                    maxRetryCount: 5,
                    maxRetryDelay: System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                    errorNumbersToAdd: null))
                .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information)
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors());
```

If I try accessing the data I get the following message:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RetryLimitExceededException: The maximum number of retries (5) was exceeded while executing database operations with 'MySqlRetryingExecutionStrategy'. See the inner exception for the most recent failure.
 ---> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.OpenTcpSocketAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 1146
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 438
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.ConnectSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, String logMessage, Int32 startTickCount, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 403
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.ConnectSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, String logMessage, Int32 startTickCount, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 408
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 98
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 128
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(ConnectionPool pool, Int32 startTickCount, Activity activity, Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 929
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 423
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlRelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass30_0`2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IAsyncEnumerableOfTConverter`2.OnWriteResume(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TAsyncEnumerable value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonCollectionConverter`2.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCoreAsObject(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCore[TValue](Utf8JsonWriter writer, TValue& value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultFilters>g__Awaited|28_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I really do not understand why it works locally or with the workbench but not with an extern database. If anyone of you has an idea what the problem is I would appreciate it.

**EDIT**:
The previous error message is the one i get in the console. Since someone asked for the inner error here is the message I get in the browser:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RetryLimitExceededException: The maximum number of retries (5) was exceeded while executing database operations with 'MySqlRetryingExecutionStrategy'. See the inner exception for the most recent failure.

 ---> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.OpenTcpSocketAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 1146

   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 438

   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.ConnectSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, String logMessage, Int32 startTickCount, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 403

   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.ConnectSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, String logMessage, Int32 startTickCount, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 408

   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 98

   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 128

   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(ConnectionPool pool, Int32 startTickCount, Activity activity, Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 929

   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 423

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)

   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlRelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass30_0`2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()

   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IAsyncEnumerableOfTConverter`2.OnWriteResume(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TAsyncEnumerable value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)

   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonCollectionConverter`2.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)

   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)

   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)

   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCoreAsObject(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)

   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCore[TValue](Utf8JsonWriter writer, TValue& value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, WriteStack& state)

   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultFilters>g__Awaited|28_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)

   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)



HEADERS

=======

Accept: text/plain

Host: localhost:7041

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0

:method: GET

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3

Cookie: PHPSESSID=2tr9dnf5vkacnspngoa54l7qga

Referer: https://localhost:7041/swagger/index.html

TE: trailers

sec-fetch-dest: empty

sec-fetch-mode: cors

sec-fetch-site: same-origin
```

I hope this is what you asked for.

Comment: And what's the inner exception details?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct IP address and you have network connectivity to the database server and port?

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes, I already checked 10 times or so. It is the same address and credentials I use in the mysql workbench

Comment: Can you check if it works locally?

Comment: @AliZedan Yes, if the database is on the same Computer and I use localhost it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I really do not understand why it works locally or with the workbench
> but not with an extern database. If anyone of you has an idea what the
> problem is I would appreciate it.

Well, based on your description, error stack trace and from code snippet numerous aspects need to check, first of all, when you are saying exernal database what did you exactly pointed to? Is it a cloud database, or any other server?

If that is cloud database please make sure you have configured that with correct parameters. In addition to this, also check your server or database instance also running and you have installed correct `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` version.

Apart from this, please double check your external database provider, to check their log or ask them why you are not able to connect with database.

Most importantly, based on your error message, its seems did able to connect as the retries got faild which you have set as 5.

Sometimes, defining server and port in seperate order can also cause the connection failure. Thus, you can do as following:

```
"Server=127.0.0.1:3306;Uid=username;Pwd=password;Database=dataBaseName;"
```

OR

```
"Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Uid=username;Pwd=password;Database=dataBaseName;"
```

**Note:** Please double check the port number and CamelCase order. Because, you haven't followed my any specific case.

Furthermore, firewall restriction also need to be taken care, you need to check your and exter provider firewall defination. Last but not least, make sure there's no IP restirction or white listing issue in either side.

**Note:** Please [refer to this document](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/), I think it can help you different configuration pattern.

Comment: Yeah, the Port seemed to be the problem, writing it together with the ip solved the problem. Still seems pretty stupid that there is an option to define the port seperatly that causes problems.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, as assumed, numerous issue can cuase connection failure. Glad to know that your issue has been resolved.